# get previous code git merge

Tags: git, github, merge

I don't understand how exactly Git works.

I have a branch, `branch1`, with this code:

```
<?php
$this = array(
    "aa" => 1
);
```

and another branch, `branch2`, with:

```
<?php
$this = array(
    "aa" => 1,
    "bb" => 2
);
```

When I do:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
```

I have no conflicts and I have exactly the branch1 code, I would like to have the branch2 code.

```
Master - - - \ - - - - - - - - - - -Branch1
              \
               \- - - - Branch2
```

Edit:

I think there some auto conflicts resolutions I'd like to avoit it

Comment: Have you committed the contents of branch 2?

Comment: That depends on when the different changes were introduced. `git merge` uses a three-way merge strategy by default, comparing the two tip version with the youngest common ancestor. If the changes in branch 2 were already present when they diverged, and branch 1 was changed afterward, those changes will supersede the ones in branch 2. You can look at [`man git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) for different merge strategies.

Comment: No I had my branch1 code when diverged

Comment: Look at the man page anyway. There are options to override the merge with one side of it, thereby creating a merge commit and converging the branches, but accepting all changes from one side instead of using an actual marge strategy

Comment: What's on master branch? Please do `git checkout master` and write what is there.  Since this is their nearest common ancestor, it's important.

Comment: @skalee I just post an exemple, the real code have 150 files

Comment: I think there some auto conflicts resolutions I'd like to avoit it

Comment: how many commits are there? Can you post the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --left-right --boundary branch1...branch2`?